# Leave state open "in background". Hide, but don't leave state in Angular UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, embed, angular-ui

I have an Angular app using Angular UI for states, with 2 or more states. In one state, the user might begin writing text, for example, or play a Youtube video. Currently, if they switch states, videos will stop playing and other data will be lost. The states are not nested in one another, and that doesn't really fit with how the app is laid out.

Is there a way to not destroy states when changed and leave them open "in the background"?

My other idea was to combine these states into one state and just use ng-hide to toggle between these views. But this will increase load times, and there could be a large number of streams in the future.

Another idea is open to open the Youtube video in a higher state when it's played.

If it helps, imagine my states are link browser tabs and I want the user to be able to switch between them.

Any native Angular UI solution for this or other ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the YouTube-video, as that will be in the DOM, and stuff in the DOM gets replaced between states.

For other data, you might consider using angular services for storing your variables between views. Services are independent of views and great for these sort of things.

You could perhaps also store in your service where in the YouTube video the user was when the view gets changed. That way you can resume playing, when the view gets changed back again.

Service:

```
app.factory('MainService', function(){
    var service = {};
    service.model = 'Main page';

    return service;
});
```

Controller using the service:

```
app.controller( 'MainCtrl', function ( $scope, MainService ) {
    $scope.service = MainService;    
});
```

And finally in the template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="service.model">
```

Here's the example using services and ngRoute: 
http://jsfiddle.net/NEuJ6/180/

edit: If you want to store something in your service on state change, then use

```
$scope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 
   service.storedStuff = 'Something';
});
```

In your controller.